# How can I create Pod that incorporates other pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I have a collection of Pods, that make up essentially common, custom extensions and classes I share between my apps.

Right now these are part of my Podfile as such

```
  pod 'AuthUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/AuthUtils.git', :tag => '4.2'

  pod 'AutoLayoutUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/AutoLayoutUtils.git', :tag => '2.5'
```

I'd like to combine these in a common Utils Pod, something like

```
pod 'MyAppUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/MyAppUtils.git', :tag => '1.0'
```

With the ability to install everything using `MyAppUtils` but also just install some modules, for example

```
pod 'MyAppUtils/AuthUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/MyAppUtils.git', :tag => '1.0'
```

I have seen this behaviour with https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift and https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit for example, but I do not understand how to implement this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subspecs` to achieve that. You can go to a project that implements `subspecs` and find their `podspec` file to use as reference, or you can find more info in the [CocoaPods Specs Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html)

This is an example of a subspec:

```
  s.subspec 'SwiftStdlib' do |sp|
    sp.source_files  = 'Sources/Extensions/SwiftStdlib/*.swift'
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know that was what they were called to even begin googling. Very helpful thank you :)

Comment: Would I place a podspec file in Sources/AuthUtils also? Say for example AuthUtils has some external dependencies I would like to install too

Comment: You can add dependencies to your subspecs as well, like this `sp.dependency 'SwifterSwift/Shared'`. These dependencies can be other subspecs or other pods, and will be installed only if you install that subspec.

Answer (score 1):

These subprojects with the format "Project/Subproject" are called [CocoaPods Subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec). These are subprojects with specific source folders.

From the CocoaPods website and supposing your code for AuthUtils is inside the `Sources/AuthUtils` folder, you could add the following to your `Podfile` for MyAppUtils:

```rb
subspec 'AuthUtils' do |sp|
  sp.source_files = 'Sources/AuthUtils'
end
```

Once published, you should now be able to install the pod using

`pod 'MyAppUtils/AuthUtils', :git => 'https://github.com/xxxxx/MyAppUtils.git', :tag => '1.0'`

Comment: Would I place a podspec file in Sources/AuthUtils also? Say for example AuthUtils has some external dependencies I would like to install too

Comment: No, not really - these are best maintained if you keep it all on your main Podfile. You can add a dependency to AuthUtils by adding something like `sp.dependency 'RestKit/ObjectMapping'` to the file within the `do |sp|` block.